# Autocomplete form fields on dynamically created ones

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have been trying solutions for similar problems for hours now, all I could find is autocomplete for one field.

Here is my form code:

```
<div class="row form-group">
        <label>1</label>
            <div class="col col-sm-1"><input type="text" id="code1" name="code[]" placeholder="Code" class="form-control" required></div>
            <div class="col col-sm-4"><input type="text" id="id2" name="product[]" placeholder="Produit" class="form-control" required></div>
            <div class="col col-sm-1"><input type="text" id="id3" name="package[]" placeholder="Cdt" class="form-control" required></div>
            <div class="col col-sm-1"><input type="text" id="id4" name="qte[]" placeholder="Qté" class="form-control" required></div>
            <div class="col col-sm-1"><input type="text" id="id5" name="price[]" placeholder="Prix Unit" class="form-control" required></div>
            <div class="col col-sm-1"><input type="text" id="id6" name="vat[]" placeholder="TVA" class="form-control" required></div>
            <div class="col col-sm-1"><input type="text" id="id7" name="lot[]" placeholder="Lot" class="form-control" required></div>
            <div class="col col-sm-1"><input type="text" id="id8" name="ddp[]" placeholder="DDP" class="form-control" required></div>
            <div onclick="addRow(this.form);"><i class="btn-sm btn-primary fa fa-plus-circle"></i></div>
    </div>
```

And here is the javascript to autocomplete + add rows:

```
var rowNum = 1;
function addRow(frm) {
    rowNum ++;
    var row = '<div class="row form-group" id="rowNum'+rowNum+'">'+
                                    '<label>'+rowNum+'</label>'+
                                    '<div class="col col-sm-1"><input type="text" id="code1" name="code[]" placeholder="Code" class="form-control" required></div>'+
                                    '<div class="col col-sm-4"><input type="text" id="id2" name="product[]" placeholder="Produit" class="form-control" required></div>'+
                                    '<div class="col col-sm-1"><input type="text" id="id3" name="package[]" placeholder="Cdt" class="form-control" required></div>'+
                                    '<div class="col col-sm-1"><input type="text" id="id4" name="qte[]" placeholder="Qté" class="form-control" required></div>'+
                                    '<div class="col col-sm-1"><input type="text" id="id5" name="price[]" placeholder="Prix Unit" class="form-control" required></div>'+
                                    '<div class="col col-sm-1"><input type="text" id="id6" name="vat[]" placeholder="TVA" class="form-control" required></div>'+
                                    '<div class="col col-sm-1"><input type="text" id="id7" name="lot[]" placeholder="Lot" class="form-control" required></div>'+
                                    '<div class="col col-sm-1"><input type="text" id="id8" name="ddp[]" placeholder="DDP" class="form-control" required></div>'+
                                '<div onclick="removeRow('+rowNum+');"><i class="btn-sm btn-danger fa fa-minus-circle"></i></div>'+
                                '<div onclick="addRow(this.form);"><i class="btn-sm btn-primary fa fa-plus-circle"></i></div>';
    jQuery('#itemRows').append(row);
    frm.add_qty.value = '';
    frm.add_name.value = '';
}

function removeRow(rnum) {
    jQuery('#rowNum'+rnum).remove();
}
```

And:

```
var mySource = [{"label":"7545","id2":"Product 001","id3":"50","id5":"3850.00","id6":"19"},
{"label":"9071","id2":"Product 002","id3":"1","id5":"103867.13","id6":"0"},
{"label":"6701","id2":"Product 003","id3":"50","id5":"2556.3","id6":"17"}];

$("#code1").autocomplete({
  source: mySource,
  select: function(event, ui){
    if(ui.item){
      $("#id2").val(ui.item.id2);
      $("#id3").val(ui.item.id3);
      $("#id5").val(ui.item.id5);
      $("#id6").val(ui.item.id6);
      return ui.item.label;
    }
    else{
      $("#id2").val('');
      $("#id3").val('');
      $("#id5").val('');
      $("#id6").val('');
    }
  },
  change: function(event, ui){
    if(ui.item){
      $("#id2").val(ui.item.id2);
      $("#id3").val(ui.item.id3);
      $("#id5").val(ui.item.id5);
      $("#id6").val(ui.item.id6);
    }
    else{
      $("#id2").val('');
      $("#id3").val('');
      $("#id5").val('');
      $("#id6").val('');
    }
  }
});
```

Autocomplete is only working on the first row. But not the dynamically added rows!

Any idea how I can enable autocomplete on newly added rows too?

Comment: Please try to simplify the problem before posting the question. You can for example reduce the number of div elements . This way it's easier to understand the problem.

Comment: @optimalLight , I will try to do that in the future. The issue was solved by Swati . Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using **same ids** for mutliple elements first change them to *class* . Then , change `$("#code1")` to `$(".code1")` then inside `select` & `change` function use `$(this).closest(".form-group")` to refer div where autocomplete is present and use `.find()` to get required inputs and add values there .

Next , when you add new elements you need to initialize your autocomplete . So, use `jQuery('#itemRows .form-group:last .code1').autocomplete(options);` this will get last `form-group` which is added and then get `.code1` intialize it .

Lastly , to remove div when `-` is clicked use `jQuery(rnum).closest(".form-group").remove();` where *rnum* refer to current element which is clicked then using closest remove entire div.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var mySource = [{
    "label": "7545",
    "id2": "Product 001",
    "id3": "50",
    "id5": "3850.00",
    "id6": "19"
  },
  {
    "label": "9071",
    "id2": "Product 002",
    "id3": "1",
    "id5": "103867.13",
    "id6": "0"
  },
  {
    "label": "6701",
    "id2": "Product 003",
    "id3": "50",
    "id5": "2556.3",
    "id6": "17"
  }
];
var rowNum = 1
//use like this ..because mutliple places
var options = {
  source: mySource,
  select: function(event, ui) {
    var selector = $(this).closest(".form-group") //here get closest form-group
    if (ui.item) {
      //find required inputs and then add value there
      selector.find(".product").val(ui.item.id2);
      selector.find(".package").val(ui.item.id3);
      selector.find(".price").val(ui.item.id5);
      selector.find(".vat").val(ui.item.id6);
      return ui.item.label;
    } else {
      selector.find(".product").val('');
      selector.find(".package").val('');
      selector.find(".price").val('');
      selector.find(".vat").val('');
    }
  },
  change: function(event, ui) {
    var selector = $(this).closest(".form-group")
    if (ui.item) {
      selector.find(".product").val(ui.item.id2);
      selector.find(".package").val(ui.item.id3);
      selector.find(".price").val(ui.item.id5);
      selector.find(".vat").val(ui.item.id6);
    } else {
      selector.find(".product").val('');
      selector.find(".package").val('');
      selector.find(".price").val('');
      selector.find(".vat").val('');
    }
  }
}

function addRow(frm) {
  rowNum++;
  //remove ids .. add classes
  var row = '<div class="row form-group" id="rowNum' + rowNum + '">' +
    '<label for="codes">' + rowNum + '</label>' +
    '<div class="col col-sm-1"><input type="text" name="code[]" placeholder="Code" class="form-control code1" required></div>' +
    '<div class="col col-sm-4"><input type="text" name="product[]" placeholder="Produit" class="form-control product" required></div>' +
    '<div class="col col-sm-1"><input type="text" name="package[]" placeholder="Cdt" class="form-control package" required></div>' +
    '<div class="col col-sm-1"><input type="text" name="qte[]" placeholder="Qté" class="form-control qty" required></div>' +
    '<div class="col col-sm-1"><input type="text" name="price[]" placeholder="Prix Unit" class="form-control price" required></div>' +
    '<div class="col col-sm-1"><input type="text" name="vat[]" placeholder="TVA" class="form-control vat" required></div>' +
    '<div class="col col-sm-1"><input type="text" name="lot[]" placeholder="Lot" class="form-control lot" required></div>' +
    '<div class="col col-sm-1"><input type="text" name="ddp[]" placeholder="DDP" class="form-control ddp" required></div>' +
    '<div onclick="removeRow(' + rowNum + ');"><i class="btn-sm btn-danger fa fa-minus-circle"></i></div>' +
    '<div onclick="removeRow(this);"><i class="btn-sm btn-primary fa fa-plus-circle">-</i></div>';
  jQuery('#itemRows').append(row);
  //get last added form-group in that code1 initialize it ..
  jQuery('#itemRows .form-group:last .code1').autocomplete(options);
}

function removeRow(rnum) {
  jQuery(rnum).closest(".form-group").remove(); //remove closest form-group
  var index = 1;
  //rstart id and count
  $("#itemRows .form-group").each(function() {
    index++;
    $(this).attr("id", "rowNum" + index);
    $(this).find("label[for=codes]").text(index)
  })
  rowNum--; //decremnt count...
}


$(".code1").autocomplete(options);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="row form-group">
  <label>1</label>
  <div class="col col-sm-1"><input type="text" id="code1" name="code[]" placeholder="Code" class="form-control code1" required></div>
  <div class="col col-sm-4"><input type="text" id="id2" name="product[]" placeholder="Produit" class="form-control product" required></div>
  <div class="col col-sm-1"><input type="text" id="id3" name="package[]" placeholder="Cdt" class="form-control package" required></div>
  <div class="col col-sm-1"><input type="text" id="id4" name="qte[]" placeholder="Qté" class="form-control" required></div>
  <div class="col col-sm-1"><input type="text" id="id5" name="price[]" placeholder="Prix Unit" class="form-control price" required></div>
  <div class="col col-sm-1"><input type="text" id="id6" name="vat[]" placeholder="TVA" class="form-control vat" required></div>
  <div class="col col-sm-1"><input type="text" id="id7" name="lot[]" placeholder="Lot" class="form-control lot" required></div>
  <div class="col col-sm-1"><input type="text" id="id8" name="ddp[]" placeholder="DDP" class="form-control ddp" required></div>
  <div onclick="addRow(this.form);"><i class="btn-sm btn-primary fa fa-plus-circle">+</i></div>
</div>

<div id="itemRows">

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much , your code worked perfectly.
There was a little issue, when I used the code on my entire page, it didn't work at first, then I found other js and jquery assets in the footer that were conflicting your code, so I declared the jquery assets you used right at the end of the page, and that solved the problem.